# What happen when a class has name as Integer,String etc

Tags: java

I am new in Java. I have a question as below:
 I have a class which has name Integer. When I call Integer in another class, I cannot use java.lang.Integer, just can use my Integer class. Why does it that?

Thanks all. :)
 The classes as below:

```
//My Integer class
    public class Integer{ //do something}
//Another class
    public class Test{int i = Integer.parseInt("1");}
```

Comment: please post the `another class` code

Comment: For one of the classes, you have to use the fully qualified name everytime it appears.

Answer (score 5):

> When I call Integer in another class, I cannot use java.lang.Integer, just can use my Integer class.

You *can*, you just have to be explicit:

```
int x = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(someString);
```

The reason is that Java has fully-qualified names (like `java.lang.Integer`) and a working set of *simple* names derived from your `import` statements and `package`. If you create a class called `Integer`, that simple name will be in your working set, superceding the default `Integer` = `java.lang.Integer` mapping.

[This Oracle Java tutorial on packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) may be useful.

---

Side note: You don't "call" a class, you call methods and constructors. You "use" or "refer to" a class.